# Use parent class to style next element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a code block like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="btn-group">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to style "child" div without direct styling. Like

```
.child{
color:red;
}
```

I need to use "wrapper" div styles apply to "child" div but not to apply "wrapper".

I tried using this but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
.wrapper > .btn-group + .child{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Try `.wrapper > .btn-group > .child`?

Comment: @ShioT how is that not direct styling? That does the same what .child would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div + p`

Selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements.

You need to use `>` (selects direct child

```css
.wrapper > .btn-group > .child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div class="child">
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) or [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) instead of [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) since its child of `.btn-group` and not the sibling.

```
.wrapper > .btn-group > .child{
  color:red;
}

// or 

.wrapper > .btn-group  .child{
  color:red;
}
```

```css
.wrapper > .btn-group > .child{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="btn-group">
  <div class="child">sss
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.wrapper > .btn-group .child` for this. check updated snippet below...

```css
.wrapper > .btn-group .child{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
div wrapper
 <div class="btn-group">
 div btn group
  <div class="child">
  Div Child
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use something like this if you dont want to follow the entire markup structure

```
.wrapper .child {
color:red
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.wrapper>.btn-group>.child {color:red}
```

Comment: You should consider adding an explanation for your code.